# java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I'm getting the following exception.

Caused by:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer

with the following code

```
List queryResult = query.list();

for (Iterator<Object[]> it = queryResult.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Object[] result = it.next();
    Integer childId = (Integer) result[0];
    Integer grandChildCount = (Integer) result[1];
    CompanyNode childNode = childNodes.get(childId);
    childNode.setHasChildren(grandChildCount != 0);
    childNode.setIsLeaf(grandChildCount == 0);
}
```

at this line

```
Integer grandChildCount = (Integer) result[1];
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm trying it out now in production, hopefully it works now.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use:

```
Integer grandChildCount = ((BigInteger) result[1]).intValue();
```

Or perhaps cast to `Number` to cover both `Integer` and `BigInteger` values.

Answer (score 19):

As we see from the javaDoc, `BigInteger` is not a subclass of `Integer`:

```
java.lang.Object                      java.lang.Object
   java.lang.Number                       java.lang.Number
      java.math.BigInteger                    java.lang.Integer
```

And that's the reason why casting from `BigInteger` to `Integer` is impossible.

Casting of java primitives will do some conversion (like casting from `double` to `int`) while casting of types will never transform classes.

Comment: I was confused because the local database was generated with an Integer by hibernate and the same should of happened with production, but it was changed to an int in production.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
((BigDecimal) volume).intValue();
```

I use `java.math.BigDecimal` convert to `int` (primitive type).

It is worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

`java.lang.Integer` is not a super class of `BigInteger`.  Both `BigInteger` and `Integer` do inherit from `java.lang.Number`, so you could cast to a `java.lang.Number`.

See the java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Answer (score 1):

The column in the database is probably a `DECIMAL`. You should process it as a `BigInteger`, not an `Integer`, otherwise you are losing digits. Or else change the column to `int`.