# Getting a Java Class Cast Extension when attempting to connect to a MySQL Database with NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm currently trying to connect a Java application in `NetBeans` to interact with a `MySQL Database` and I am getting the following error when trying to connect:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long)

Anyone know why this would be happening or how I could fix it?  As far as I know the JDBC URL I am giving it to make the connection is correct.

To clarify, there is no code in the project that I am attempting to run, I am only attempting to connect to the 'MySql Database'.

Comment: try showing us the code where it does this

Answer (score -1):

Cast that into `BigInteger`. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510982/java-math-biginteger-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-integer/9511010) question.

Comment: The error is not in application code. The error is occurring when NetBeans is attempting to connect to MySQL.