# my sql :java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I am doing a simple program in netbeans.
Following is the Exception caused

> > java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

```
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="home/signup">
    Enter id:<input type="text" name="userid">
    Enter password<input type="password" name="pwd1">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">

    </form>
</body>
```

Servlet:

```
   {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login", "root","12345678");
            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();

            int n=stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `login`.`tables` (`"+request.getParameter("userid")+"`) VALUES ('"+request.getParameter("pwd1")+"');");

            out.println("Rows updated: "+n);



        }catch(Exception ee){out.println(ee.toString());}
    }
}
```

I tried doing everything and could not find a solution. Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: SqlInjection alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510982/java-math-biginteger-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-integer)

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. no that Question code has interger values conversion.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. Als be aware that your insert query is 1) incorrect as you try to put a value in the column list and 2) very unsafe because it is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection as you are using direct user input in a query without using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the syntax, the query that you wrote is wrong. You can check the insert statement format [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html). So basically what you should write is something in the line of:

```
insert into login.tables (user_id, password) values("some_user", "s3cr3t")
```

instead, it seems that you are not listing the column `names` first, then assigning the `values`, but putting the username value in the column `names` space and the password in the `values` part.

Comment: I tried using this  syntax,Still the Exception Exists.

Comment: Can you update the question with the modification that you applied?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just updated my jdbc connector/j drivers, I was using old version of drivers. Issue solved